# How to create constraint for specific characters in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I was trying to create a constraint for the book ID that the remaining 3 characters after BID must be 001 until 999. What can I do instead of using **%** ?

```
CREATE TABLE Book
(
    [Book ID] CHAR(6),
    [Title] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Genre] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Author] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Price] DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Book_PK PRIMARY KEY ([Book ID]),
    CONSTRAINT chk_BookID  CHECK ([Book ID] like 'BID%'),
);
```

Comment: So you are intentionally designing your table to hold a maximum of 999 rows (making assumptions) - why? And what do you expect to happen when Book "BID010" is deleted? You have a gap - are you expecting that gap to be removed or reused? Why not just make Book ID a numeric[3,0] datatype and add a computed column for your "visual" needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server supports characters classes in `LIKE`:

```
CONSTRAINT chk_BookID  CHECK ([Book ID] like 'BID[0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

Note:  I would recommend that you rename the column to `Book_ID` or `BookID`.  Having spaces in column names just clutters queries.